# How does multithreading work on a singe-core system?

Tags: multithreading

When multiple threads run on a single-core system , are those threads running simultaneously or sequentially with a fast context switch(which gives a feeling of threads running simultaneously)?
Thanks

Comment: The exact same way that 6 threads run on a 4-core system.  They all get a chance to run, context switches are required.

Comment: Isn't it obvious? How could they run simultaneously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many modern processors adapt techniques that allow them to execute several threads on a single core. Such techniques are called *Simultaneous multithreading* (or *SMT*). For instance, "Hyper-threading" is the Intel's implementation of SMT.

SMT implies that a core can fetch and execute two or more instructions from different threads simultaneously, in one cycle. If the OS also knows how to work with SMT, it can schedule threads in a way that actually allows executing different threads on the same core simultaneously. In some cases it might give nearly the same boost as executing threads on two (or more in some processors) cores.

Otherwise, it's only context switching.

Comment: Thanks that helped , BTW Is it the same for multi core systems , I mean is it just usually context switching in multi core systems too or do they run actually simultaneously  ?

Comment: On multicore systems they actually run simultaneously. Plus, multicore systems can also implement SMT, thus potentially providing even more parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

With a single CPU core, different threads don't literally run simultaneously, but the OS can prempt one thread and let another thread run.